# Can we prove that the "Center of mass" of a homogeneous rigid body is at its "Geometric center"?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, geometry, rigid-body-dynamics

I know that for basic shapes like a solid cube or a solid sphere the proof is simple. But if we had a homogeneous rigid body with an arbitrary shape, can we prove that the body's "[Center of mass](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass)" is exactly at its "[Geometric center](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_center)"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from the [definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Center_of_mass). Given a volume $V$ with mass $M$ and density $\rho(\textbf{r})$ the position of the center of mass is:

$$\textbf{r}_{CM}={1\over M}\int_V \rho(\textbf{r}) \textbf{r} dV$$

However if $\rho(\textbf{r}) = \rho_0={M\over V}$ i.e. the system is homogeneous

$$\textbf{r}_{CM}={1\over M}{M\over V}\int_V \textbf{r} dV={1\over V}\int_V \textbf{r} dV$$ which now is the definition of geometric center.

Comment: In general relativity theory this is not so clear anymore., see e.g. https://www.nsf.gov/awardsearch/showAward?AWD_ID=1005560

Comment: nice, I will look into it. Yet I think OP did not have that in mind (:

Comment: OP did not list general relativity as a topic. @JalfredP's answer is perfectly good. BTW, it is a simple result from first year analytical mechanics (classical).