# How can I prove that the center of mass for an arbitrary uniform triangle is at the geometric centroid?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

Show that for an arbitrary uniform triangle $\rm ABC$, with $\rm A$ at $(x_1, y_1)$, $\rm B$ at $(x_2, y_2)$, $\rm C$ at $(x_3, y_3)$, the center of mass $(x_{\rm cm}, y_{\rm cm})$, is simply defined by $x_{\rm cm}=(x_1+x_2+x_3)/3$, and $y_{\rm cm}=(y_1+y_2+y_3)/3$.

So I did this problem by placing my origin such that the base lies on the $x$-axis and then integrating that way. That way the new coordinates of the vertices are $\rm A$ $(0,0)$, $\rm B$ $(x_2,y_2)$, and $\rm C$ $(x_3,0)$. I ended up with $x_{\rm cm} = (x_2 + x_3)/3$ and $y_{\rm cm} = y_2/3$. I kinda feel like this was cheating though. How can I end up with the exact relationship that was asked for while keeping the triangle at arbitrary coordinates? Keep in mind that the problem was asked with integration in mind, so I don't think another method would be accepted.

Comment: I edited your post to format the math. Please click 'edit' to see the syntax and try to use similar formatting in future posts, it's much easier to read.

Comment: Isn't this trivial? The centroid is the centre of area. If the triangle density is uniform then centre of mass coincides with centre of area. Perhaps you are really asking, "How can I prove that the co-ordinates of the centre of mass are ...?"

Comment: Thanks I'll try my best to post with similar syntax in the future. Is there a page a that you can link me to that has more details about proper math syntax?

Comment: Mathjax reference: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Yes, I am trying to prove explicitly that the center of mass coordinates are at the geometric centroid.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can we prove that the "Center of mass" of a homogeneous rigid body is at its "Geometric center"?](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/291237)

Comment: @sammygerbil  I don't think that is a duplicate. This really gets to the question "is the geometric center equal to the average of the coordinates of the three corners". That's different than the question answered in the duplicate you suggested.

Comment: @Floris : I am going by the title here. As in my earlier comment, the title and the text seem to be asking different questions. Elvis' response does not clarify.

Comment: Discussed in page -148 [here](https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/keph107.pdf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not really cheating - you did a linear coordinate transformation to make the problem easier, and that's allowed.

However, it would be good to complete your proof by showing the transformation needed to get from the initial coordinates to the "easy" coordinates, then applying the inverse transformation to your result in order to get the required result.

Alternatively, you can do the integration "the hard way". In that case, you want to demonstrate that the center of mass (that is, the first moment of area) is at the requested location. This is most easily done by transforming the coordinate system to be centered at the assumed center of mass, then performing the integral. The integral comes to zero - demonstrating that the assumed center of mass is the actual center of mass.

Comment: I can introduce the variables u = x - $x_1$ and v = y - $y_1$ so as to put A$(x_1, y_1)$ at the origin but I'm not sure how I would then rotate the triangle while holding A fixed so that C$(x_3,y_3)$ is now on the x-axis.

Comment: Don't rotate the axes. You can integrate from the lower to the upper bound - no need for the triangle to be aligned with the x axis. Just calculate the length of each segment - the integral will be something like $\int (y_2(x)-y_1(x))~x~dx$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ are the coordinates of the edge of the triangle at position $x$.

Comment: Yeah i'm trying to figure out the syntax but I am failing.

Comment: Suggestion - start an "edit" of your question. Type in the equation you want to format. There is a "live" preview below the question - when you get it right, you will see the correct formatting. Then copy the complete equation, and "discard" the edit to the question. Then paste into a comment. That's what I did until I got comfortable that I could get it right.

Comment: Thanks that was really helpful. So this is what I meant the first time.  
Assuming the coordinate transformations that I posted previously, would I then have to split up the integral into two parts like the following       $u_{cm}$ = $\int_0^{u_2}$($\frac{v_3-v_2}{u_3-u_2}$)$u^2$du + $\int_{u_2}^{u_3}$[($\frac{v_3-v_2}{u_3-u_2}$)u + $v_3$ -($\frac{v_3-v_2}{u_3-u_2}$)$u_3$]u du ?